# How can I keep the Windows 8 virtual keyboard from popping up?

Tags: windows-8, virtual-keyboard

I am the unwilling recipient of Windows 8. Lenovo couldn't fix the new Windows 7 Ultrabook I bought, so they sent me a Yoga laptop, with touch-screen and Windows 8.

Once I bought a start menu replacement, I don't mind Windows 8 too much - it's ugly, but most things work as well as Windows 7. But the thing that drives me crazy, endlessly, is the virtual keyboard popping up when I'm trying to do something else (well, just about anytime, since I almost never use it to type). It's like a giant Clippy that covers half the screen.

I haven't figured out what causes it to pop up. It seems pretty random, and sometimes it goes away before I can even reach for the escape key. Sometimes it comes up when I'm typing, sometimes when my hands are nowhere near the keyboard. Sometimes several times a minute, sometimes not for hours.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Need a screenshot to understand it properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if it is a on screen keyboard:

[image]

Or a TabTip keyboard

[image]

For **On-Screen Keyboard** go to Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Ease of Access Center -> Use the computer without a mouse or keyboard and uncheck Use On-Screen Keyboard (if checked). Also check if the Windows + Volume Up key do something. It could be set to On-Screen keyboard in Ease of Access Center -> Make touch tablets easier to use.

For **TabTip keyboard**, you can remove it by removing any shortcut for it from taskbar ( right click -> toolbars -> Touch Keyboard) and then killing process by typing this in cmd:

taskkill /F /IM TabTip*

(You could also consider putting this command into a batch file and executing it at startup as windows 8 restarts TabTip processes if it finds a touch input device, though it doesn't come forward on its own)

Comment: Yes, that switched off the Keyboard. Sadly the task bar icon is still there which seems to be quite a buggy and often takes up 50% of the taskbar.

Answer (score 11):

I also have a Lenovo Yoga. I also had to deal with this. It's... Just stupid, I know. What follows is an explanation and a solution.

**Why you're having this problem:**

Windows 8.1 was designed with a heavy emphasis on touch screens ("traditionally" on tablets.) If a touch screen is present, Windows 8.1 assumes that a keyboard is not, so any time you poke your finger onto the screen within a text box, a keyboard pops in (because it thinks you don't have one available, so you'll obviously need a way to type in yonder text box, dig?) However, if you have a convertible machine like your Yoga, which has *both* a touch screen and a physical keyboard, Windows doesn't know that; It just thinks you have a touch screen ONLY, with no keyboard, so it keeps pushing that annoyingly redundant On-Screen Keyboard up in yo' grill even though you've already got a perfectly functioning "IRL" keyboard right in front of you. Dumb, ya? *Dumb, dumb, dumb!*

To make things more confusing, this behavior is only designed into METRO apps, and not Desktop apps (with SOME exceptions, like, say, Google Chrome, which have the Metro-style touch-text-box,-get-On-Screen-Keyboard-popup-automatically enabled as a "feature" you can't turn off)

Generally, with Desktop apps, you won't get a forced On-Screen Keyboard if you touch the screen, so this is why you may not see the strange behavior for hours at a time - you're using a desktop application.

All of this is why the keyboard popping in seems random to you; because the interface for Windows 8.1 was not designed consistently.

Does that make sense? No? Welcome to Windows 8.1.

As for the sudden disappearances, the On-Screen Keyboard will go *away* suddenly if you touch any of the physical keys. It's 8.1's way of saying, "Whoops! Sorry, I didn't see that physical keyboard there." Except it doesn't remember the whoops two seconds later.

I've called both Microsoft and Lenovo directly about this. Their take? The truth is, Microsoft did not design Windows 8.1 with convertibles (like your Yoga) in mind. If you have both a keyboard and a touch screen, you are going to experience this behavior. As of this point in time, there is no "fix."

...So, there's the "why".

**As to the "how", first lets look at a proposed solution that came before this post:**

Disabling the keyboard by stopping the service *does work* - it will nuke the On Screen Keyboard right outta the park - but the *Yoga* converts into a *tablet* as well as a laptop, and at that point you'll *want* that onscreen keyboard back - so the thought of digging into multiple screens and scrolling down to find that *one tiny setting* buried in a long scrolling list of other tiny settings each and every time you just want to flip your dam* computer into a tablet, is exasperating.

**HERE IS A WORKAROUND THAT LETS YOU HAVE YOU CAKE AND EAT IT TOO:**

We're going to make it so that the On-Screen Keyboard will NOT pop into view without your permission, but still have the On-Screen Keyboard available to you when you use tablet mode. Better yet, it's not that complicated to do... Ready?

**Step #1. Go to the Charm search (Win + C)**

**Step #2. Type in "On-Screen Keyboard"** An On-Screen Keyboard will appear, but it will look different than the one you're used to. This one has a Win7 style minimize button.

**Step #3 *Click that minimize button!*** The new-style On-Screen Keyboard will minimize to the Taskbar on your Desktop, out of your way.

Done.

Now, *DON'T TOUCH IT!* Just leave it open & minimized in the Taskbar.

As long as that new keyboard sits minimized in the Taskbar, when you touch or click on any text box *in any context* the OS will think that the On-Screen Keyboard is *already* enabled, except it won't shove it back in front of your face, it will stay neatly minimized. You won't see it.

Meanwhile, the hardware keyboard on your Yoga will continue to work like normal. Success!

When you want to use the computer in regular tablet mode again, just switch back your Desktop (Win + D) and close the On-Screen Keyboard like you would any regular Desktop app.

Coolio.

So now, when you flip your Yoga back to tablet mode, you'll still have regular access to that On-Screen Keyboard when you need it, in its intended context.

(You'll still have to reengage that alternate On-Screen Keyboard each time you come back to laptop mode from tablet mode, but it only takes a second to do so. ....I *did* say this was a workaround, not a fix.)

'Best,

- J.E.

Comment: what you describe is no normal windows behaviour. when a physical keyborad is present, no virtual touch keyboard is shown. seems more like a special problem of your yoga to me.

Comment: @thewhiteambit no, that's simply not true. Happens to me on other non-yoga tablets. Windows simply doesn't care if there's a physical keyboard present, and keeps shoving the on screen keyboard at me, inconsistently depending on the application (e.g. Chrome and Outlook do it, most other applications don't)

Comment: dunno, works perfect on my surface

Answer (score 4):

The fastest and most reliable way to disable the Windows 8 on screen keyboard is by stopping the service that starts it and disabling it from running.

## How To: Disable the Windows On-Screen Keyboard Service

- Press the Windows key + R
- Type "services.msc" and press Enter
- Scroll down to "Touch screen keyboard and handwriting panel"
- You can either right click and "Stop" or you can double-click and change it from "Automatic" startup to either "Manual" or "Disabled".

[image: Disabled]

Comment: note this also kills the on screen writing.

Comment: This is the best answer for me, because I use my Yoga in tablet mode a bunch, and occasionally I still have to type. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is another programmatically solution.

You can create an **TouchKeyboardHelper.cs** class and declare system message to find the soft keyboard and force to close it.

The **TouchKeyboardHelper.cs** must be like:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Windows.Devices.Input;

namespace Application_Photo_GRDF.Common
{
public static class TouchKeyboardHelper
{
#region < Attributes >

private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112; // Flag to received/send messages to the system.
private const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060; // Param to indicate we want to close a system window.

#endregion < Attributes >

#region < Properties >

public static bool KeyboardAttached
{
get { return IsKeyboardAttached(); }
}

#endregion < Properties >

#region < Methods >

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName); // To obtain an active system window handler.

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam); // To send a message to the system.

/// <summary>
/// To detect if a real keyboard is attached to the dispositive.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private static bool IsKeyboardAttached()
{
KeyboardCapabilities keyboardCapabilities = new KeyboardCapabilities(); // To obtain the properties for the real keyboard attached.
return keyboardCapabilities.KeyboardPresent != 0 ? true : false;
}

/// <summary>
/// To close the soft keyboard
/// </summary>
public static void CloseOnscreenKeyboard()
{
// Retrieve the handler of the window 
int iHandle = FindWindow("IPTIP_Main_Window", ""); // To find the soft keyboard window.
if (iHandle > 0)
{
SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0); // Send a close message to the soft keyboard window.
}
}

#endregion < Methods >
}
}
```

An to use that helper in our code add something like......

```
if (TouchKeyboardHelper.KeyboardAttached)
{
TouchKeyboardHelper.CloseOnscreenKeyboard();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of the virtual keyboard popup by doing this:

1. Press the Windows key + R
2. Type "services.msc" and press Enter
3. Scroll down to "Touch screen keyboard and handwriting panel"
4. You can either right click and "Stop" or you can double-click and change it from "Automatic" startup to either "Manual" or "Disabled".

I right clicked and stopped, then went back and did it again and double clicked and chose "disable" from the drop down window, making sure to click the "apply" button, then "ok" button, and then this:

1. Press Windows key + R.
2. Type control and press enter to open the control panel.
3. Type ease of access center in the control panel and open it.
4. Click "use the computer without a mouse or keyboard".
5. If "use on-screen keyboard" is checked, uncheck it and save the changes.

Again, make sure to click the "apply" button followed by "ok". I first checked  "use the computer without a mouse or keyboard" (this was previously unchecked) - then I immediately unchecked it again, followed by "apply" and "ok". This solved my problem on a Windows 8.1 ASUS tablet laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works

> 1. Right click *TaskBar*-> *Properties*
> 2. Click *ToolBars*
> 3. Uncheck *Touch Keyboard*

Comment: This is just a quote from the accepted answer.

Comment: Am sorry I dint check entire answer...