# How to stop On-Screen Keybord from popping up every window?

Tags: windows-8.1, on-screen-keyboard

So before my On-screen keybord would pop up only at start up even though it was disabled. It was annoying but I could deal with it.

Now it pops up almost everytime I open a new window or when an program needs a permission and I need to click Yes/No.

I've have it turned off in Ease-Of-Access and disabled in services but it still keeps happening. How do I get it to turn off?

I am on Windows 8.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently remove/disable Touch Keyboard in Windows 8 taskbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/488322/permanently-remove-disable-touch-keyboard-in-windows-8-taskbar)

Answer (score 0):

What might help is checking Task Manager "Startup" tab and looking for any entries about the OSK.

You can also try disabling it from regedit. I was able to find mentions of setting the key "ShowTabletKeyboard" to "0" (disabled) under

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI

That might only be for the logon screen but it could be worth a try.

This similar post has some good suggestions too. [How can I keep the Windows 8 virtual keyboard from popping up?](https://superuser.com/questions/585568/how-can-i-keep-the-windows-8-virtual-keyboard-from-popping-up)

Comment: I forgot to mention I did the regedit and it was already set to 0. I'll see if there is anything else I could try in the other thread.